# Why was this question deleted without notice?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

One of my friends, who is new to this site, asked a very good [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36190387/how-can-i-add-slide-numbers-to-a-powerpoint-presentation-using-open-xml-net-sdk) (IMO) only to find it was deleted without any notification or explanation.  If I remember correctly, he answered his own question after finding the solution, adding value to the site, and helping others who may have the same problem. I know the question was not a duplicate, or spam, as I assisted him in trying to find any previously asked questions (or answers) that would resolve the problem.

Can a moderator, or someone with over 10k rep, advise why this was removed?

There may be a valid reason - I would just like to know why.  Also, why was there no communication on why it was removed?

Comment: It was deleted by a moderator on March 24th. Maybe they'll come and explain, there are indeed no comments on both the question and answer.

Comment: Thanks Tunaki - We were quite shocked to find out it was removed!

Comment: For <10k http://i.stack.imgur.com/qZuBK.png

Comment: Yes, adding to Tunaki's comment, I would say the language of the answer was a little careless.

Comment: Don't know as I'd call it a *good* question but yes deletion seems a little harsh.

Comment: Having seen it again I would agree, but he is new to the site and recieved no guidance.  Thanks all!

Comment: Would not it be nice if _one of the friends_ of that person helped with the writing style and adding code to answer?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The "Never mind" at the beginning of your friend's self-answer made it sound like they weren't all that interested in keeping the question and that the Q&A wasn't actually adding any value to the site. That's probably why. I don't see any flags on either the question or the answer that could have prompted a moderator to respond in this manner.

I undeleted the question and removed the fluff from the answer.

I agree there should have been some form of communication, for example closing the question as "a problem that can no longer be reproduced", prior to deleting the question. I normally only straight up delete absolute garbage posts like

> how fix my sql code plz help me how fix my sql code plz help me how fix my sql code plz help me how fix my sql code plz help me how fix my sql code plz help me how fix my sql code plz help me how fix my sql code plz help me how fix my sql code plz help me

where it doesn't seem like any amount of communication is going to help the user.

Comment: Who wouldn't delete questions like that, but this was actually a decent problem :)

Comment: Mod probably lost his keys..or the cat ran over the keyboard again...it happens.

Comment: FWIW [particular recent feature](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/277727/165773) (not yet available for SO) suggests that communication in cases like that is rather expected to be initiated by users (who are in turn expected to be interested in keeping their content): users can ask on [per-site-meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/per-site-meta/info) about their _own_ questions even when their reputation is less than 5 and even when question is deleted

Comment: +1 for the funny garbage example